# Segmented Control false selected Index

Tags: objective-c, return, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a problem with some segmented controls:
I have a tableview with 10 cells and all cells have one segmented control.

Now my problem:
If I change the selected index of a segmented control and scroll up or down, the selected index of some segmented controls are change.

Has anyone an idea whats false?

//Edit:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier;

    CellIdentifier = @"editCell";
    cellList[indexPath.row-1] = [[MSEditCardCell alloc] init];
    cellList[indexPath.row-1] = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cellList[indexPath.row-1];
```

}

Comment: Could you post the code where you set the selected index of each segmented control? It seems to be related to cell reuse.

Comment: You most likely reuse the cell, aren't you? Don't reuse it. **Edit:** Damn. To late. ;)

Comment: Did you implement segmentedControlDelegate ? if YES, could you share the methods you have implemented ?

Comment: @Leandros The optimal way of doing is to have a model that indicates which segmented index has to be selected, and use that model, not avoiding reuse, which can have huge performance implications.

Comment: This is because your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is wrong. Show your code, someone will help you spot the problem.

Comment: @neutrino: I don't said he shouldn't reuse the cells in general. He just shouldn't reuse that particular cell. But yeah, basically your solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Durican says, this is a problem with cell reuse. You need to set up a data model that stores the information you are presenting in each cell. When the user changes the selected segment in a given cell, you need to respond to that change by updating that bit of information in your model.

Then, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you need to fetch the appropriate entry from your model and use the information to fully configure the new cell, including setting the state of the segmented control for that cell.

This is basic table view stuff, and something most people struggle with when they first start using table views.

Answer (score 0):

It's is because the cells are being reused when you scroll. Just add a iVar or a property for the cell (Boolean), and everytime you are configuring your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, make sure you set the segmentedControl accordingly to the bool you are setting

Comment: I never reuse the cells. I store them in an array an every row has his own cell.

Comment: what does your cellForRow look like then ?